# 2014/2016 Developer Edition of SQL Server (Backward Compatibility)

Tags: sql, reporting-services, compatibility

It seems the developer edition is now free to install and use (in development environments).

Our production environment is 2012 SQL Server.  Would I be able to use the 2016 developer edition to develop 2012 reports/SSIS/SSAS, or would I need to use the standard 2012 developer tools (which I guess I still need to buy?).

Thanks

Comment: NB, SQL 2014 developer edition is also now free, although I don't think that helps you here. The developer/client tools (SSMS, SSDT & SSDT-BI for SSIS/SSRS/SSAS) have always been free, the old BI tooling for your specific version are still available https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674919.aspx. As for the target database engine, report server etc., ideally you should be developing against the same version as the intended deployment.

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting to develop using 2016 local/dev server installs of the database engine, report server, etc. (ignore the tooling version for a moment) and then deploy to 2012 instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but with a few caveats.

You can develop reports with later versions of SSDT and build/deploy these to earlier versions of SSRS. You need to specify the **TargetServerVersion** in the build configuration:
e.g.

[image]

or

[image]

This will determine what RDL schema version is built and deployed, if you chose to deploy the project, as well as the build artefacts that are created locally in the Solution's bin folder.

That said, if you create a report with SSRS 2016 specific features you will get warnings (e.g. a Custom Parameter Pane) or errors (e.g. SSRS 2016 chart type) when building/deploying to earlier versions.

So it's possible, you just need to be vigilant with your process.

Comment: Can you develop for TargetServerVersion = 2012 but then deploy to 2016 targets?

Comment: While it is possible, it is far safer and less likely for there to be a problem if you develop using the correct version of SSRS for the server where you will deploy the report. If your production server is 2012, then create the reports in 2012.